# Check for multiple date ranges overlapping

Tags: python

I have an array of unordered date ranges expressed as tuples of strings in ISO date format, and need to return any of the tuples that express date ranges that are overlapped by any of the others.

Therefore the return list will be a list of tuples like the input set, except with tuples missing that express date ranges that are not overlapped by any of the other tuple date ranges.

Thus the date ranges themselves are not modified, they are just selected from the list.

Example input date ranges:

```
dates = [
     ('2021-03-01', '2021-03-31'),
     ('2021-04-01', '2021-05-15'), # overlaps
     ('2021-07-01', '2021-11-30'),
     ('2021-01-01', '2021-02-28'),
     ('2021-05-01', '2021-05-31'), # overlaps
]
```

Expected result:

```
overlapped_dates = [
     ('2021-04-01', '2021-05-15'),
     ('2021-05-01', '2021-05-31'),
]
```

Is there a light and efficient way of doing this?

Comment: `2021-11-31` is not a valid date

Comment: @Chris: None of the date *strings* are dates.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi: Thanks, noted. I will do so in future questions.

Comment: @Chris: I should have mentioned that all dates listed would be assumed as datetime objects.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming we fix november 31st to be a real date, like nov 30th, we can use pandas to do this by sorting by start date, and checking for rows where the start date is less than the previous end date, or the end date is greater than the next start date.

```
import pandas as pd


dates = [
     ('2021-03-01', '2021-03-31'),
     ('2021-04-01', '2021-05-15'), 
     ('2021-07-01', '2021-11-30'),
     ('2021-01-01', '2021-02-28'),
     ('2021-05-01', '2021-05-31'), 
]

df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns=['start','end'])
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])

df = df.sort_values(by='start')

df.loc[(df['start'].lt(df['end'].shift())) | (df['end'].gt(df['start'].shift(-1)))].astype(str).values
```

Output

```
array([['2021-04-01', '2021-05-15'],
       ['2021-05-01', '2021-05-31']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: This doesn't work, if, for instance, you change the first end-date to July instead of March. Also, I know the OP doesn't specify, but following good coding practice and Occam's Razor I'd like to see a solution without resorting to an additional dependency outside the standard library just for date calculations.